# Coverage is omitting some lines of a function while reporting

Tags: python, code-coverage

I have this function

```
def discover_item_execute(self, data):
    """ 
        discover_vim rpc handler
    :param data:
    :return:
    """
    logger.info("Processing rpc : discover_item")
    apiclient = get_vnc_client_local()

    vnc_job = VncJob(name="discover_item_" + str(uuid.uuid1()),
                     job_type='discover_item',
                     job_info=None,
                     state='submitted')

    job_id = apiclient.job_create(vnc_job)  #pylint: disable=E1101

    # Send request to core using celery client
    submit_request('discover_item', data, job_id)
    out = DiscoverItem_OutputType(job_id=job_id)
    resp_obj = DiscoverItemOutput(output=out)
    resp_str = json.dumps(resp_obj, default=obj_serializer_all)

    return resp_str
```

This gets executed as part of my test. But when I generate the coverage report I see that the lines from `submit_request` to the `return` are not showing being hit while the previous lines are shown as hit. When I run it through debugger I can see them get executed. But for some reason the `coverage` is not capturing them. Any idea what might be happening here? Why does `coverage` think those lines are not getting executed?

Comment: Can you add the coverage report output to your question?

Comment: Perhaps the `apiclient.job_create()` call is hitting some condition that makes the program exit altogether, i.e. by calling `sys.exit()`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can see the subsequent lines getting executed when I run through a debugger or put a log/print statement.

Comment: I don't know what apiclient.job_create does.  It would be odd, but it could be fiddling with the settrace function, which would interrupt coverage collection.  If you are using gevent or eventlet, you should run coverage with the `--concurrency` switch to be sure it measures properly.